# Thread never acquires shared lock

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, thread-synchronization

I was learning about the old-school Java synchronization mechanisms and stumbled upon some problems. Code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ngrahovac/Garage/commit/efbc7c6f6870bc5dd8c416ea6899e2f0bde59be8).

Consider the following test example.

From the main method, we construct a garage `Platform` object, represented by a char matrix. There are two cars already parked (denoted with *x*) and a vehicle standing in the way (denoted with *v*). Cars are entering the garage from position *(1,0)* and driving through, as shown in red, looking right and left for an available parking spot.

[image]

From the main method, thirty vehicles are created (threads) and the `start()` method is called. If there is a car in front of them blocking their way, they must call `wait()` on the shared `Platform.lock` object.

The `Observer` class is in charge of printing the current state of the garage to the console.

Where problems occur is with the `MysteryVehicle` thread, whose only job is to remove the obstacle (denoted with *v*) and let the cars pass in an orderly fashion. It seems that this object never acquires the lock's monitor.

**Main class**

```
package garage;

import garage.model.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Platform platform = new Platform();
        Vehicle.platform = platform;
        platform.print();

        Vehicle[] vehicles = new Vehicle[30];
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            vehicles[i] = new Vehicle();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            vehicles[i].start();
        }

        Observer observer = new Observer();
        observer.platform = platform;
        observer.setDaemon(true);
        observer.start();

        MysteryVehicle mysteryVehicle = new MysteryVehicle();
        mysteryVehicle.start();

        try {
            mysteryVehicle.join();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                vehicles[i].join();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        platform.print();

        System.out.println("END");
        System.out.println(platform.flag); // checks whether wait() was called anytime

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Platform class**

```
package garage.model;

public class Platform {

    public boolean flag = false; // indicades whether wait() was called anytime

    public char[][] fields = new char[10][8];
    public static final Object lock = new Object();

    public Platform() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                fields[i][j] = '.';

        fields[1][0] = fields[2][0] = 'x'; // already parked cars
        fields[4][1] = 'v'; // obstacle
    }

    public void print() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    System.out.print(fields[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Vehicle class**

```
package garage.model;

public class Vehicle extends Thread {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 0;

    private int block = 1;

    public static Platform platform;
    public boolean moving = true;

    public void run() {
        y++; // entrance

        while (moving) {
            if (block == 1) {
                while (moving && platform.fields[x + 1][y] == 'v')
                    try {
                        synchronized (Platform.lock) {
                            Platform.lock.wait();
                            platform.flag = true;
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                synchronized (Platform.lock) {
                    x++;
                    Platform.lock.notifyAll();
                    yield(); // suggest another vehicle should get processor time
                }

                // looking left and right for an available spot
                if (platform.fields[x][0] != 'x' && platform.fields[x][0] != '*') {
                    platform.fields[x][0] = '*'; // park
                    moving = false;
                } else if (x < 8 && platform.fields[x][3] != 'x' && platform.fields[x][3] != '*'
                        && platform.fields[x][2] != 'v') {
                    platform.fields[x][3] = '*';// park
                    moving = false;
                }

                // checking if we reached the end
                if (moving && x == 9) {
                    block = 2;
                    move(); // transfer to the second block of the garage
                }
            } // end block 1

            if (block == 2) {
                // looking left and right for an available spot
                if (platform.fields[x][7] != 'x' && platform.fields[x][7] != '*') {
                    platform.fields[x][7] = '*'; // park
                    moving = false;
                } else if (x < 8 && platform.fields[x][4] != 'x' && platform.fields[x][4] != '*'
                        && platform.fields[x][5] != 'v') {
                    platform.fields[x][4] = '*'; // park
                    moving = false;
                }

                while (moving && platform.fields[x - 1][y] == 'v')
                    try {
                        synchronized (Platform.lock) {
                            Platform.lock.wait(); // waiting for the mystery vehicle to disappear
                            platform.flag = true;
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                if (moving) {
                    synchronized (Platform.lock) {
                        x--;
                        Platform.lock.notifyAll();
                        yield();
                    }
                }

                if (x == 1) {
                    y++;
                    moving = false;
                }

            } // end block 2
        } // end moving
    }

    private void move() {

        while (y != 6) {
            if (y + 1 == 'v')
                try {
                    synchronized (Platform.lock) {
                        platform.flag = true;
                        Platform.lock.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            synchronized (Platform.lock) {
                y++;
                Platform.lock.notifyAll();
                yield();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Observer class**

```
package garage.model;

public class Observer extends Thread {
    public Platform platform;

    {
        setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (Platform.lock) {
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                    platform.print();
                    yield();
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Platform.lock.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**MysteryVehicle class**

```
package garage.model;

public class MysteryVehicle extends Vehicle {

    {
        setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (Platform.lock) {
            System.out.println("And the vehicle disappears!");
            platform.fields[4][1] = '.';
        }

    }
}
```

After a while, `Observer` produces the following output which never changes. It seems the MysteryVehicle never got processor time and all of the cars are stuck.

[image]

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

Since `yield()` doesn't release the lock, I tried to use `wait()` instead - and got `IllegalMonitorStateException`, even though `wait()` is inside the block synchronized on the same lock!

I tried changing `Observer` into a `TimerTask`, scheduled by a `Timer` for every 5 seconds. The output was way faster than that and the program wouldn't terminate.

Comment: Your `Observer.run()` method keeps `Platform.lock()` locked almost 100% of the time.  It unlocks the lock once every two seconds, but the very next thing it does is re-lock the lock, which makes it extremely unlikely that any other thread will be able to acquire the lock.

Comment: I bet that `yield()` does not do what you think it does.  (Hint: In most situations, it is perfectly acceptable for `yield()` to do _nothing at all_.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow I thought this would increase the chance this thread will give up its time slice and the scheduler will schedule another one.

Comment: `yield()`, _might_ do that, or it might do nothing, but it won't unlock the lock in either case.

Comment: If I replace `yield()` with `wait()` that does unlock the lock, I get an `IllegalMonitorStateException`, although `wait()` is in the block synchronized on the same lock.

Comment: `wait()` means `this.wait()`, but `this` is not the lock object.  You could use `Platform.lock.wait()` instead, but then that opens the question, what is it waiting for?  Maybe you could `Platform.lock.wait(2000)` instead of `sleep(2000)`, though IMO, that's a bit of a hack.

Comment: @SolomonSlow silly mistake, fixed it and it worked. Thanks for helping me understand what was going on here.